# Adding MySQL servers/ data nodes into database clustering without restarting mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster

I currently have mysql clustering up and running. For high scalability is there a way to include either mysql node, data nodes, or management nodes without restarting the entire cluster. I wish to understand how is it implement or is there a documentation I can read. I believe only the latest version can support this. I am running NDB 7.0. I am aware that I am able to add the nodes online, but it requires me perform a rolling restart.

What other approach I can take to implement this without restarting in my network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pre-defined the MySQL Server slots in your config.ini file then you don't need a rolling restart when you actually run your mysqld process. If you didn't include the empty slots then you'd need a rolling restart after adding them

note that the rolling restart doesn't bring the cluster down - it can continue to serve read and write requests while adding nodes

Answer (score 0):

As Mat said, you must predict how many new data nodes you'll have in your cluster and avoid to perform a cluster rolling restart. You must pay more attention regarding the cluster security when you have many [ndbd] sections in config file.